# How can I have my inherited TextBox use the style of the Button Type

Tags: wpf, styles, basedon

I am using a custom TextBox that inherits from TextBox:

```
Public Class MyTextBox: Inherits TextBox
    ...
End Class
```

I want this class to use the Style that is defined in the classic.xaml ResourceDictionary. I tried this:

```
 <Style x:Key="{x:Type uc:MyTextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}"/>


    <Style x:Key="{x:Type TextBox}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBoxBase}}"
       TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <!-- predefined style in classic.xaml-->
    </Style>
```

But I am greeted with an error message stating that the style can only be based on a type of IFrameworkInputElement.

This should be trivial, shouldn´t it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `TargetType="{x:Type uc:MyTextBox}"` to your style.